# Error with terraform init in a docker container -- x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, docker-compose, certificate, terraform-provider-aws

I have

```
$ cat terraform.Dockerfile
FROM alpine
MAINTAINER Carlos Nunez <dev@carlosnunez.me>
RUN wget -O /tmp/terraform.zip https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.9/terraform_0.12.9_linux_amd64.zip && \
    unzip /tmp/terraform.zip -d /
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache ca-certificates curl
USER nobody
```

When I do

```
$ docker-compose run terraform /terraform init
```

I get

```
$ docker-compose run terraform /terraform init
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.12.9
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.12.9
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/terraform", "init"}
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /.terraformrc
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] File doesn't exist, but doesn't need to. Ignoring.
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"init"}
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [ERR] Checkpoint error: mkdir /.terraform.d: permission denied

Initializing the backend...
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: no config given or present on disk, so returning nil config
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend has not previously been initialized in this working directory
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] New state was assigned lineage "cff52927-0e9b-8ef4-8aeb-2b176dbc40a6"
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: using default local state only (no backend configuration, and no existing initialized backend)
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: instantiated backend of type <nil>
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/"
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/"
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [INFO] Failed to read plugin lock file .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: open .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: no such file or directory
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend <nil> does not support operations, so wrapping it in a local backend
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] backend/local: state manager for workspace "default" will:
 - read initial snapshot from terraform.tfstate
 - write new snapshots to terraform.tfstate
 - create any backup at terraform.tfstate.backup
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: reading initial snapshot from terraform.tfstate
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: snapshot file has nil snapshot, but that's okay
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: read nil snapshot
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "."
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] checking for provider in "/"
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] plugin requirements: "aws"=""
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] Service discovery for registry.terraform.io at https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [TRACE] HTTP client GET request to https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json

Initializing provider plugins...
- Checking for available provider plugins...
2020/03/29 08:25:36 [DEBUG] Failed to request discovery document: Get https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Registry service unreachable.

This may indicate a network issue, or an issue with the requested Terraform Registry.


Error: registry service is unreachable, check https://status.hashicorp.com/ for status updates
```

I saw several links online indicating same/similar error that was solved by installing `curl`.

I have `curl` on the container, I verified it.

```
$ docker-compose run terraform curl --version
curl 7.67.0 (x86_64-alpine-linux-musl) libcurl/7.67.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1d zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.40.0
Release-Date: 2019-11-06
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

I also have the certificates installed:

```
$ docker-compose run terraform ls -lR /etc/ssl
```

Here is output of `curl -v`

```
$ docker-compose run --entrypoint 'curl -v --insecure https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json' terraform
*   Trying 151.101.190.49:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to registry.terraform.io (151.101.190.49) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Fastly, Inc.; CN=q2.shared.global.fastly.net
*  start date: Apr  1 14:48:12 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Aug 29 17:17:53 2020 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; ST=CA; O=paloalto networks; OU=IT; CN=decrypt.paloaltonetworks.com
*  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate in certificate chain (19), continuing anyway.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55cce9444220)
> GET /.well-known/terraform.json HTTP/2
> Host: registry.terraform.io
> user-agent: curl/7.67.0
> accept: */*
>
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200
< server: Cowboy
< cache-control: stale-if-error=31536000, public, max-age=3600
< content-security-policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://www.google-analytics.com https://cdn.segment.com https://www.googletagmanager.com https://a.optnmstr.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://p.typekit.net https://use.typekit.net; img-src 'self' data: https: https://www.google-analytics.com; font-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com https://fonts.googleapis.com https://fonts.gstatic.com https://use.typekit.net; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com https://api.segment.io https://sentry.io https://api.omappapi.com https://api.opmnstr.com https://api.optmnstr.com
< content-type: application/json
< feature-policy:
< last-modified: Fri, 10 Apr 2020 08:49:04 GMT
< referrer-policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-frame-options: DENY
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< via: 1.1 vegur
< via: 1.1 varnish
< accept-ranges: bytes
< date: Sat, 11 Apr 2020 06:07:54 GMT
< via: 1.1 varnish
< age: 63
< x-served-by: cache-dca17758-DCA, cache-pao17436-PAO
< x-cache: HIT, HIT
< x-cache-hits: 1, 1
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< content-length: 62
<
{"modules.v1":"/v1/modules/","providers.v1":"/v1/providers/"}
* Connection #0 to host registry.terraform.io left intact
```

Comment: Same issue. When I change my IP (using VPN) it becomes fine for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Run `update-ca-certificates` after you instal the ca-certificates package. Docker layer caching may prevent it from re-running the install step, and the CA Certificates are likely out of date.

Comment: This did not fix the issue.

Comment: What is the output when you run `docker-compose run terraform curl -v --insecure https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json`?

Comment: Updated original post

Comment: There is a self-signed certificate in the chain that might cause a problem, but seems unlikely. There is an official docker image for Terraform that might work better, or you may want to delete your local images and attempt rebuilding.

Comment: Did you force docker-compose to rebuild after updating the Dockerfile?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, Absolutely. I  forced a rebuild using --no-cache

Comment: A few more things... not sure if any of them will be helpful. Try changing your `RUN apk...` command to `RUN apk add --update --no-cache openssl curl ca-certificates` and put it before you download Terraform. You might also want to use `FROM alpine:latest` too, so you make sure you aren't using some cache version somehow accidentally. Lastly, have you tried running this without `USER nobody` yet? Perhaps the /etc/ssl path doesn't have correct permissions for nobody.

Answer (score 0):

Running update-ca-certificates didnt work for me. I tried below method of mapping node's cert file copy to container's cert file and it worked.

try to check if the node on which docker container is installed is able to connect to terraform.

Do *"curl -v [https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json"](https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json%22)* on both, docker node as well as container.

If node's curl works and container's fails, then try to create copy of the cert file. Cert file location can be fetched from curl command output as below.
After creating copy map this certificates file to container's certificate file (location for which you will get in container's curl command).

If your both of our curl fails try updating your certificate and then try above method.

[link for image containing curl cmd output and the certificate location in the request header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADriA.png)